# How to label on an edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make some graphs, but I need to put labels on the edges but I tried when I try to put the label is in the middle of the edge. can anybody help me?

Also, could someone tell me how can I increase the edge thickness and edge color?[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill = black, draw, color=#1, outer sep = 2, circle, minimum size = 3pt, scale = 0.75}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[Bullet=black,label=left : {$z_1$}] (z1) at (-6, 2){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=left : {$z_2$}] (z2) at (-6, 0){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_1$}] (s1) at (-4, 4){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_2$}] (s2) at (-4, 2){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_3$}] (s3) at (-4, 0){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_4$}] (s4) at (-4, -2){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_1$}] (v1) at (-1, 6){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_2$}] (v2) at (0, 4){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_3$}] (v3) at (0, 2){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_4$}] (v4) at (0, 0){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_5$}] (v5) at (0, -2){};
\node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_6$}] (v6) at (-1, -4){};

\draw (z1)--(s1);
\draw (z1)--(s2);
\draw (z1)--(s3);
\draw (z2)--(s2);
\draw (z2)--(s3);
\draw (z2)--(s4);
\draw (s1)--(v1);
\draw (s1)--(v2);
\draw (s1)--(v4);
\draw (s2)--(v3);
\draw (s2)--(v5);
\draw (s2)--(v6);
\draw (s3)--(v1);
\draw (s3)--(v4);
\draw (s3)--(v6);
\draw (s4)--(v2);
\draw (s4)--(v4);
\draw (s4)--(v3);
```

Comment: having seen your profile you have not accepted any answer till date nor up-voted any answer for its usefulness to your requirement-- any particular reason for not accepting any answer till date--it would be customary to show your appreciation for a member who would have spent time to resolve your problem dont you think so

Comment: would you like to accept the answer below or is there some other requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{Bullet/.style={fill = black, draw, color=#1, outer sep = 2, circle, minimum size = 3pt, scale = 0.75}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[Bullet=black,label=left : {$z_1$}] (z1) at (-6, 2){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=left : {$z_2$}] (z2) at (-6, 0){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_1$}] (s1) at (-4, 4){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_2$}] (s2) at (-4, 2){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_3$}] (s3) at (-4, 0){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$s_4$}] (s4) at (-4, -2){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_1$}] (v1) at (-1, 6){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_2$}] (v2) at (0, 4){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_3$}] (v3) at (0, 2){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_4$}] (v4) at (0, 0){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_5$}] (v5) at (0, -2){};
    \node[Bullet=black,label=above: {$v_6$}] (v6) at (-1, -4){};
    
    \draw (z1)--node[left]{C$_4$}(s1);%<-------------add label
    \draw (z1)--(s2);
    \draw (z1)--(s3);
    \draw (z2)--(s2);
    \draw (z2)--(s3);
    \draw (z2)--(s4);
    \draw (s1)--(v1);
    \draw (s1)--(v2);
    \draw (s1)--(v4);
    \draw (s2)--(v3);
    \draw (s2)--(v5);
    \draw (s2)--(v6);
    \draw (s3)--(v1);
    \draw (s3)--(v4);
    \draw (s3)--(v6);
    \draw (s4)--(v2);
    \draw (s4)--(v4);
    \draw (s4)--(v3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit**

Other options can be added

```
\draw (z1)--node[left,above, sloped]{C$_4$}(s1);
```

[image]

```
 \draw (z1)--node[left,above, sloped, yshift=-2em]{C$_4$}(s1);
```

[image]

```
 \draw (z1)--node[left,above, sloped]{\scriptsize C$_4$}(s1);
```

[image]

```
\draw (z1)--node[left,above, sloped, red]{\scriptsize C$_4$}(s1);
```

[image]

**edit**

for edge color and thickness

```
 \draw[red,ultra thick] (z1)--(s2);
```

[image]

Comment: how can i change the edge color and the thickness?

Comment: pleasse see edit